# /bin/su: Permission denied in CentOS can not set su - root

Tags: terminal, centos, root

I'm trying to set myself as a root and once I type in `su - root` in the terminal it just give me an error saying  `/bin/su: Permission denied`  so I checked the permission in that file

`-rwsr-x--- 1 root wheel 24120 Mar 30  2011 su*`

I'm wondering why I can't use this I'm trying to install some plugin and it asks me to use root thats why I needed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to be a member of the wheel group. This restricts su logins to "trusted" users

Comment: to be a member of wheel group I have to ask root to add me in the group but Godaddy disable root by default for security reason and they asked me to use su but `su` it doesn't work thats why :(

Comment: does root not have a password? if so try "sudo su -"

Comment: myaccount is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: if you could please add the permissions of the /bin/su and if root has a password set. Also the contents of the group file may help